# Смена внешнего вида персонажа во время игры

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Хочу, чтобы по достижению определенного количества очков менялся внешний вид персонажа. Интересен способ реализации. 
*Не использую libgdx.*
Для подгрузки персонажа использую

```
 player = new Player(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rob1), 52, 79, 2);
```

Comment: Вопрос в том, как снова загрузить картинку?

Comment: да, подгрузить новую картинку во время игры.

Comment: @GuardFromUA реализовать в классе Player метод принимающий новую картинку и подменяющий ею старую нет возможности по каким-то объективным причинам?